# Firebase Cloud Messaging for Xcode Erroe 'MessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing push notifications into an IOS app with firebase. I followed the documentation but my messages are not being received. I have this alert

"'MessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling."

and "'appData' is deprecated"

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
      print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

      let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
      // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Message Data", remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, I have been on this and can't figure it out!

Comment: Did you try a web search for that error message?

Comment: Yes but nothing really helped. Thanks do inquiring though!